# How do I compute the distribution of the limit of this martingale.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

For $X_n \in [0,1]$ and $r\in [0,1]$, we define the following martingale: 
$$ 
X_{n+1} =
  \begin{cases}
                                   1 -r + rX_n & \text{with probability $X_n$} \\
  rX_n & \text{with probability $1 - X_n$}
  \end{cases}
$$

By the martingale convergence theorem, I know this converges almost surely. But how I expicitly compute the distribution of $X_{\infty}$? Is there a result I should keep in mind?

Comment: Shouldn't that be $X_{n+1} =
  \begin{cases}
                                   1 -r + rX_n & \text{with probability $X_n$} \\
  rX_n & \text{with probability $1-X_n$}
  \end{cases}$?

Comment: @ProfessorVector corrected it

Comment: You can find inspiration in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032117/martingale-convergence-proof.

Comment: That's good, but have you really checked the martingale property, or the conditions of the martingale convergence theorem? It would be a good idea to show that work, so we can judge what kind of answer you need. No offense intended, but experience shows that in this place, words after "I know" are to be taken with a grain of salt (or a handful, more often).

Comment: This question is also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/243554/36150

Comment: @saz It's not just related, it's the same problem, with $\alpha=1-r$ and $\beta=r$. The answer is a bit of an overkill, because the martingale converges a.s., too, so every pathwise limit has to be a fixed point of $x\to rx$ or $x\to1-r+rx$, i.e. $\in\{0,1\}$, and the probability $P(X_\infty=1)=EX_\infty=EX_0$ is easy.