# Levy's 0-1 law and Martinagle

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales

This is from Durrett's probability: Theory and Examples Exercise 4.6.6.

> Let $X_n \in [0,1]$ be adpated to $\mathcal{F}_n$. Let $\alpha,\beta>0$ with $\alpha+\beta=1$ and suppose
> $$\mathbb  P(X_{n+1}=\alpha +\beta X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n)=X_n,\quad \mathbb 
>  P(X_{n+1}=\beta X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n)=1-X_n$$
> Show $\mathbb P(\lim_n X_n= 0 \;\text{or}\; 1) =1.$

I know there is question [Martingale convergence proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032117/martingale-convergence-proof) here but can't we prove this using levy's 0-1 law?

What can we say about levy's 0-1 law regarding Martingale Sequence?

Answer (score 1):

$X_n$ is a martingale, and so converges (boundedly) to a random variable $X_\infty$. You'll be able to write a recursion for the second moments $\Bbb E[X_n^2]$, leading, after a passage to the limit as $n\to\infty$, to the conclusion that $\Bbb E[X_\infty^2] = \Bbb E[X_\infty]$.